# Key error in merge function between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a question. I have two data set as under,

```
df1

Sl No  Address  
1      1111
2      2222 
3      2345
4      7890
5      0987
6      3456 
7      1233
```

```
df2

email  Add.
AA    A123
AA    1111 
AA    99999
BB    a9999
BB    345689
BB    345699 
CC    1233
```

I'm trying to merge the two dataframe based on address column and bring column named email to the df1.

I have renamed the column, and passed the merge function as under.

```
df2.rename(columns = {'Add.':'Address'}, inplace = True)
df1 = df1.merge(df2['email'],how="left", on = "Address")
```

I'm not sure why but i'm getting a key error

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1682             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1683         else:
-> 1684             raise KeyError(key)
   1685 
   1686         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'Address'
```

I verified the files, column named "Address" is present in the source file. Not sure why merge function is saying otherwise.
Note -  Both the address columns in df1 and df2 are objects

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Do not select the email column when you `merge` , this will make the merged df become series

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2[['Address','email']], how = "left", on = "Address")
```

Comment: I would want only email column to be merged to df1, bcoz df2 has a lot of irrelevant columns which would make the file size large to run other analysis

Comment: @Sid select your column for df2 , check the update

Comment: I used the above code, but getting a key error, if use ```df1 = df1.merge(df2, how = "left", on = "Address")``` it works but when I use the code suggested I get key error. completely not sure why

Comment: @Sid it work on my side....